# Ember-Cloaking not uncloaking views

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to integrate [ember-cloaking](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking) into my app, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Currently, I have a list of 20 items that get displayed using this code:

```
{{each bands itemView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band'}}
```

This works exactly as I would expect. So I changed to this code:

```
{{cloaked-collection content=bands cloakView='matrix_band' itemController='matrix_band' defaultHeight=200 offsetFixed='.matrix-header'}}
```

When it first loads, it shows the 6 visible items on the screen, which is what I expected. But when I scroll down, I just get the `Loading...` text. It never actually uncloaks the items though. If I scroll all the way down the page and inspect the DOM, I can see that it cloaks and uncloaks the first 6 items properly, but it won't work with the remaining 14 items.

How can I fix this? Is it possible that this is caused by Ember 1.5.1 instead of 1.3.0 (what the demos are using)?

EDIT: I was able to cobble a fix together by replacing lines 135 and 136. Here's the original:

```
scrollOffset = this.get('wrapperTop') >> 0,
viewTop = $view.position().top + scrollOffset,
```

Here's my fix:

```
scrollOffset = $(window).scrollTop(),
viewTop = $view.position().top - scrollOffset,
```

This seemed to work OK, but the scrolling seemed pretty rough (which could just be my PC/browser). Also, it seems like a bit of a hack. I know that there are several different positions for every DOM element, but I don't know much about them. It seems odd that the ember-cloaking code would work for Discourse, and plenty of other people, but fail for me. Could that possibly have something to do with the way my HTML and CSS are structured?

EDIT2: I tested on my iMac, which is much faster than my Macbook, and the scrolling was still very choppy. So either my change is causing a significant performance regression, or my views are just slow to draw because of their complexity. The latter seems more likely given that the view is pretty complicated, but I'm open to other answers.

And I'd still like to know if there's anything I can do to fix this bug other than modifying the source.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions there. On the issue of choppiness, I'd simplify the views to a single element and retest. That way you can know if it's the view or your processor.
On the issue of the items not displaying, are they off-screen or hidden? That would tell you if there's a problem in your layout or some bad interaction in the code.